# Django rest framework URL Filter - Edit/Update Instance returned via filter method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I've had success using filter_fields to return a single filtered result list.

I want to update to this result.

Is there a way to update a filtered single result? via a URL pattern like the below?

LocalHost:8080/PriceMaster/?ISIN=aaa&valuedate=2018-01-01

I know if i use the primary key at the end of the URL instead of the filter I can update the instance.

I feel I may have to make a second view (inheriting from one of these API views) with a a new url?

RetrieveUpdateAPIView, RetrieveDestroyAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Is there a way to keep it within the 1 ViewSet and what might it look like?

This is my current **views.py**

```
class PriceMasterViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PriceMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)
    lookup_field = 'django_id'
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('ISIN', 'ValueDate',)
    model = PriceMaster
```

When I make a PUT, PATCH or POST within Postman to the URL I get the error "Method Not Allowed"

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

As expected when I add a second viewset (inheriting RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView) and a new URL I can retrieve the filtered instance and make changes.

additional view

```
class PriceMasterEditSet(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = PriceMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)
        if 'ISIN' in self.request.query_params and 'valuedate' in self.request.query_params:
            filter_kwargs = {'ISIN': self.request.query_params['ISIN'],
                            'valuedate': self.request.query_params['valuedate']}
        else:
            raise Http404('Missing required parameters')

        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

additional URL added to patterns

```
url(r'^PriceMaster/edit', PriceMasterEditSet.as_view())
```

**I still ask can I do this within the 1 ViewSet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems like you are confused about the RESTful concept and your thought process and design seem to be more like the RPC API pattern. There's a [great article about this](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) by the author of REST where he explain the differences.

Basically, with a REST API you should let the HTTP verbs define the action you want to do, while in RPC you have different URL's for each action that you want to make, e.g. Edit, Delete, Update etc. This seems to be the approach that you're doing. If you use Django **Rest** Framework, I suggest you don't do it like this and instead follow the RESTful pattern.

## Solution to your specific problem

Your filtered view is a list view, not a detailed view. You filter a list of objects by query parameters and your response is a list of objects `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`. `PUT` requests that update the object should be done against a **detailed view**, not a **list view**.

In your case, the list view would be `http://localhost:8080/PriceMaster/` and the detailed view would be `http://localhost:8080/PriceMaster/1` where the number in the end is the primary key of the object you want to view.

The **List View** accept `POST` (create)  and `GET` (read) while the **Detailed View** accept `DELETE`, `PUT` (update) and `PATCH` (partial update).

The `ModelViewSet` will set up the routing for both the list view and the detailed view by default. There's nothing you have to do to make it work.

Comment: Thanks I accept this and your belief of my confusion around REST. I shall read the article outlined. I'm dealing with a legacy SQL database with composite column primary keys and am trying some work arounds because i dont' really have the luxury of an "ID" column that i think was provided in your solution.

Comment: @GlennSampson I'd say that your `django_id` is probably Django's Primary key for each object. Anyway, if you want to accept the answer you have to press the check mark next to my answer. I hope I was of assistance.

Comment: You are correct, I had implemented the django_id column for testing